# Laravel 5 Entrust update user roles

Tags: php, laravel-5

I create a role-based project with Laravel 5 and Entrust, everything works fine until I try to update a user's role list, the bloody "Integrity constraint violation" reminds me that when calling

```
$user->attachRoles($roles);
```

It does not delete the user's roles first, so I check the interfaces of usertrait,then come up with

```
$user->detachRoles($user->roles);
$user->attachRoles($roles);
```

The code looks pretty ugly, and I think there is three SQL been executed

- find user's roles
- delete the relations
- add new relations

I was really hoping it would be like

```
$user->updateRoles($roles);
```

which can compare existing roles, and do some optimazation.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add some code formatting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use function `$user->roles()->sync($roleKeys)`. It takes array of role keys and after executing all previous roles are deleted.

Comment: I'm sorry, but who should call the sync method? `$user->sync($roleKyes)` seems not work, "undefined method" error report.

Comment: I edited the answer a bit. sync() method is run on the Eloquent relationship defining method.

Comment: I tried `$user->roles->sync($roleKeys)`, so I ended up call sync() on a Collection object. Thanks!

Comment: $user->roles()->sync($roleKeys)  -- call roles() as function not as property ->roles